# Is there a way to analyze OMS (Open Street Maps) pbf files for large areas (Germany) whithout running into memory issues?

Tags: memory, generator, openstreetmap

my task is to create a database with all street names and town names in Germany. As this is a large query I chose to download the pbf file with the python `pyrosm` package. Once I unpack the data with `OSM()` and use `get_network()` I run into memory issues as the loaded DataFrame is to large. See here for roads (this works for smaller areas such as regions in germany):

```
from pyrosm import get_data
from pyrosm import OSM
import pandas as pd

#Downloading the germany Data
de = get_data("germany")

#Turning it into an OSM object
de_osm = OSM(de)

#Extracting all driving objects, e.g. roads
roads = osm_object.get_network(network_type="driving")

#Extract all road names and turning it into a list
road_names = pd.Series(roads.name).values
road_names = list(road_names)
```

I wanted to solve this problem with generator functions but I cant seem to iterate over the data like i would with a csv file. Here are my attempts that failed:

```
osm.object= (OSM(obj) for obj in de)

#Extracting all driving objects, e.g. roads
roads = osm_object.get_network(network_type="driving")
    
#Extract all road names and turning it into a list
road_names = pd.Series(roads.name).values
road_names = list(road_names)
```

Alternative:

```
def generator_osm():
    for i in OSM(de).get_network(network_type="driving"):
        yield i

res = generator_osm()

#Extract all road names and turning it into a list
road_names = list()

for i in res:
    road_names = road_names.append(pd.Series(i.name).values)
```

Thank you in advance for any tipps you can provide :)

Comment: if you can't keep them all in memory, then you...can't. So don't do it. For example, in your last alternative, you're adding them all to a list "road_names". The generator works fine, but if you use it to create a list again, it's useless. Only keep what you need in memory, or save whatever you are collecting to a file or database before it gets to much.

Comment: @MatthiasWinkelmann . Thank you for your Tipp. Just one follow up as I'm attempting to improve my coding style/skills: So using generator functions is not the right approach here? And how do I only read out parts of a big datafile?

Comment: It’s fine… But what do you actually want to DO with that data?  You need to do it in the generator loop. If you want to find average lengths of all streets, you need to add each street‘s length to a global count, and then not retain the street itself.

Comment: I want to store all the road names in a database: 
`def road_name_generator():
        for road_name in pd.DataFrame(osm_object.get_network(network_type="driving"))['name']:
            yield road_name

    roads = road_name_generator()

    for i in roads:
        #adding names to the sql database
        create_entry(conn=conn, table='roads', values=i) `

Comment: But I'm still getting the Memory error in the generator function line: `for road_name in pd.DataFrame(osm_object.get_network(network_type="driving"))['name']:
            yield road_name `

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [`pyosmium`](https://osmcode.org/pyosmium/). It allows you to analyse osm files easily without having to deal with the geometry. I tried `pyrosm` a bit and I think it tries to create a road network when using `.get_network(…)`, which is unnecessary if you only want to know what names the roads objects in your osm files have.

I took an [example of the pyosmium documentation](https://docs.osmcode.org/pyosmium/latest/intro.html#inspecting-the-osm-objects) and applied it to collecting road names in a short example:

```py
import osmium
from collections import Counter

# handler that processes your file 
class RoadNameHandler(osmium.SimpleHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RoadNameHandler, self).__init__()
        self.road_names = []

    def way(self, o):
        if 'highway' in o.tags and 'name' in o.tags:
            self.road_names.append(o.tags['name'])


# process file
h = RoadNameHandler()
h.apply_file("germany-latest.osm.pbf")

# some examples to print & count the names
print(h.road_names)
print(Counter(h.road_names))
print(len(h.road_names))
```

This script did not take more than 500-600 MB of memory, the pbf file had to be downloaded manually from [Geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/).

P.S.: If you want to have a distinct list of the road names you can either use a `Counter()` or a `set` instead of the `list` for `self.road_names`.